# Magento 2 rules for Nginx setup

Tags: magento2, nginx

Magento 2, what are the Magento 2 rules to be added & where to run Magento 2 in Nginx.

My server guy asked me to add rule in `mnt/data/home/xyz/redirector.conf file`

But I am unaware of the what rules to be added in it.

My server Home page is working fine by all internal pages are 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento's root directory you can find a file called `nginx.conf.sample` which should contain all you need. Just give your server guy that file he should know what to do with it.

You can find the file also in the Magento github repository, for example the file of the current 2.4-development branch is located here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/nginx.conf.sample